# Будут ли данные гарантированно доставлены в том порядке, в котором я их отправляю?

Tags: c, tcp

Допустим я три раза на сервере выполняю вызов `send`

```
send(sock,"I",sizeof("I"),0);
send(sock,"Y",sizeof("Y"),0);
send(sock,"X",sizeof("X"),0);
```

На стороне клиента же три раза выполняю вызов `recv`

```
recv(sock,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
recv(sock,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
recv(sock,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
```

Я в сетях не эксперт:( tcp контролирует упорядоченную доставку пакетов, означает ли это то, что отправленные три раза данные сервером придут в том порядке, в котором я их отправил?

Comment: Можете подстраховаться mutex'ами

Comment: @EmbraceTradition, мьютексы вроде только в потоках используются,можно просто ожидать подтверждения получения данных от клиента и потом отправлять следующие, но все эти  подстраховки  лишний код и лишняя нагрузка

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον,нет, запустите и посмотрите, будет размер строки, если бы я сделал так: `char *txt="HI"; sizeof(txt);`, то вывелся бы размер указателя, не понмю почему так происходит, но это так

Comment: В TCP — гарантированно.

Comment: *"не понмю почему так происходит"* - это происходит потому что, строковый литерал является массивом, а указатель - указателем.

Comment: @user7860670, но ведь указатель указывает на строковый литерал, а имя массива указатель на его первый элемент

Comment: Размер указателя и соответственно результат sizeof не зависит о того, на что указывает указатель (и указывает ли вообще). *"имя массива указатель на его первый элемент"* - нет, массив может неявно преобразовываться в указатель на свой первый элемент в некоторых контекстах, но им не является

Comment: @user399855 https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof

Comment: нет, `sizeof("HI")` определяет размер массива из трех элементов, которым является "HI", превращения в указатель на первый элемент тут не происходит.

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо, вроде 1.5 года активно занимаюсь программированием, а такие элементарные вещи узнаю только сейчас

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я в сетях не эксперт:( tcp контролирует упорядоченную доставку пакетов, означает ли это то, что отправленные три раза данные сервером придут в том порядке, в котором я их отправил?

Да, то что контролируется **упорядоченная** доставка данных именно это и значит. TCP гарантирует это. т.е. Или будут доставлены все данные именно в том порядке в котором они отправлены, или, в случае обрыва соединения, удалённый узел не получит ничего, что идёт после обрыва, а очередной последующий вызов `send()` на локальном вернёт ошибку.

На практике это означает, что локальный узел  присваивает уникальный номер каждому отправленному пакету с данными, так что удалённый узел по этому номеру сможет определить в каком порядке идут данные даже если пакеты придут не по порядку. А для гарантии, что ничего не пропущено, локальный узел ждёт от удалённого пакет-подтверждение, что данные дошли, а если для какого-то пакета оно не будет получено, то локальный узел отправит пакет повторно. Но всё это происходит «под капотом», средствами ОС и практически незаметно со стороны программы.

Но важно, что с *программной* точки зрения в TCP нет «пакетов»: логически, он представляет двухсторонний поток данных, и эти данные могут доставляться произвольными кусками за раз. т.е. в примере выше первый же `recv()` может вернуть все данные отправленные всеми предыдущими `send()`, если буфер имеет достаточный размер или может (в вакуумно-сферическом случае) вернуть только один символ `'I'` без завершающего нуля.

Comment: Спасибо, но похоже я неправильно понял смысл слова "упорядоченный" и неправильно сформулировал вопрос